# (Seemingly) simple trigonometry problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given the diagram below, I'm trying to determine the value of $x$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

I've already run this with a few of my colleagues. It seems obvious that the problem has only one solution, but we can't find it… is trigonometry the way to go, as we thought?

[image: Diagram]

If anyone is interested, the original problem I was trying to solve was this: I was tracing a letter Z (in Inkscape) and wanted to make sure the stroke width was constant. In order to do this, I need to determine the horizontal and vertical positions for the start and end of the diagonal bar, as illustrated here:

[image: Original Z problem]

Comment: Do you mean determine $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$? How can $x$ be unique if you could rescale?

Comment: I mean $x$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$. I don't see how there could be a rescale given these 3 parameters.

Comment: Am I missing something? Isn't `x = 5c/8` ?

Comment: Oh right. The angles can change too, not just the scale.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

The trick here is to shift the perpendicular between the two diagonal lines upwards so that two similar triangles are obtained. Then, by applying the Pythagorean theorem, we obtain
$$\frac ax=\frac b{\sqrt{b^2+(c-x)^2}}$$
which may be manipulated to obtain a quadratic polynomial for $x$:
$$a\sqrt{b^2+(c-x)^2}=bx$$
$$a^2(b^2+(c-x)^2)=b^2x^2$$
$$b^2+c^2-2cx+x^2=\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^2$$
$$\left(1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)x^2-2cx+b^2+c^2=0$$
After solving, you need to check whether the obtained $x$ values are sensible – they have to lie within 0 and $c$.

Comment: Thank you. I seemed to have found another solution using Thales in a larger triangle, but this is more elegant!

Answer (score 5):

Computing total area in two ways, we have  $$ \frac{1}{b}(c+x) = \frac{1}{2}b(c-x) + a\sqrt{b^2+(c-x)^2} $$
and hence
$$\frac{bx}{a} = \sqrt{b^2+(c-x)^2} $$
The rest of proof is same as that in Parcly Taxel's solution.

Comment: The left-hand side of your first equation should be $\frac{b}{2}(c+x)$, not $\frac{1}{b}(c+x)$.  This is the area of the trapezoid with height $b$ and bases $c$ and $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define an angle $\alpha$ which defines the line between the lines noted a and b. Then we have $x=a/\cos\alpha$ and $c=x+b\tan\alpha$. Using $x=\cos^{-1}(\alpha/x)$, $\tan\alpha=\sin\alpha/\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\cos^{-1}y=\sqrt{1-y^2}$, we get $c=x+b\sqrt{1-\alpha^2/x^2}/(a/x)$. Simplifying that we get Parcly Taxel's solution.

Comment: I think this answer would be greatly improved with a diagram.

Answer (score 1):

In the diagram there is a parallelogram on the left, and a right triangle on the right, and I denote by $y$ the oblique segment which is both a side of the parallelogram and the hypotenuse of the triangle.

By computing the area of the parallelogram in two ways, we see:
$$bx = ay$$
but $y$ is also easy to determine from Pythagoras applied to the right triangle, so plugging in:
$$bx = a\sqrt{b^2+(c-x)^2}$$
which is the same equation all the other answer arrive at.